# How to call fortran functions from vb code?

Tags: vb.net, dll, fortran

I have created a dll file composed of my fortran functions and I want to use them directly from visual basic. But whatever I do I constantly get error:

```
A call to PInvoke function 'Interface!Interface.Form1::Area2D' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.
```

I followed the example code given here: [Visual Basic passing array to Fortran DLL in x64](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/visual-basic-passing-array-to-fortran-dll-in-x64)

But I could not fix it.

here is my code:

FORTRAN:

```
subroutine Area2D(polygon,A,s)


  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, ALIAS: "AREA2D" ::Area2D
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE::polygon, A,s
    integer(4)::s
    real::polygon(s,2)

    real:: A



    A=0
    do i=1,s-1
        A = A + ( polygon(i,1) - polygon(i+1,1) )*( polygon(i,2) + polygon(i+1,2) )*0.5
    end do
    A = A + ( polygon(s,1) - polygon(1,1) )*( polygon(s,2) + polygon(1,2) )*0.5
end subroutine Area2D



subroutine Centroid2D(polygon,C,A,s)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, ALIAS: "CENTROID2D" ::Centroid2D
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE::polygon, C,A,s
    integer(4)::s
    real::polygon(s,2)
    real::C(:)
    real:: A


    do i=1,s-1
       C(1)=C(1) + 1./6./A*(polygon(i+1,2)-polygon(i,2))*(polygon(i,1)*polygon(i,1)+polygon(i,1)*polygon(i+1,1)+polygon(i+1,1)*polygon(i+1,1))
       C(2)=C(2) + 1./6./A*(polygon(i,1) - polygon(i+1,1)  )* ( polygon(i,2)*polygon(i,2) + polygon(i,2)*polygon(i+1,2) + polygon(i+1,2)*polygon(i+1,2) )

    end do

    C(1)=C(1) + 1./6./A*(polygon(1,2)-polygon(s,2))*(polygon(s,1)*polygon(s,1)+polygon(s,1)*polygon(1,1)+polygon(1,1)*polygon(1,1))
    C(2)=C(2) + 1./6./A*(polygon(s,1) - polygon(1,1)  )* ( polygon(s,2)*polygon(s,2) + polygon(s,2)*polygon(1,2) + polygon(1,2)*polygon(1,2) )
end subroutine Centroid2D
```

VB:

```
    Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
    Private Declare Sub Area2D Lib "EngineX.dll" Alias "AREA2D" (<[In](), Out()> ByRef Polygon(,) As Single, <[In](), Out()> ByRef A As Single, ByRef Count As Integer)
    Dim nodes(,) As Single
    Dim nodeCount As Integer
    Dim A As Single = 0




    Private Sub DataGridView1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Leave
        If DataGridView1.RowCount >= 4 Then

            nodeCount = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

            ReDim nodes(nodeCount, 2)


            For i As Integer = 0 To nodeCount - 1 Step 1

                nodes(i, 1) = CSng(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
                nodes(i, 2) = CSng(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)

                ...

            Next

            Area2D(nodes, A, nodeCount)
            TextBox1.Text = A.ToString
        End If


    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this sort of thing, but your signature for EngineX.dll in your VB code has `<[In](), Out()>` twice. Other than that, perhaps there's some incompatibilities between `Polygon(,)` in your VB and `polygon` in your Fortran?

Comment: Actually I have solved the problem. Now the problem is fortran functions return completely stupid values. Something is wrong with passing 2d arrays.

Comment: Fortran stores arrays in column-major order. If it sees `polygon` as an `N x 2` array, then in Visual Basic you should declare the array with transposed dimensions, i.e. an `2 x N` array.